# R: Keeping Columns Based on Row Positions

Tags: r, select, where-clause, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(123)

a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,10,10)
c = rnorm(100,10,10)

my_data = data.frame(a,b,c)

          a          b         c
1  4.395244  2.8959344 31.988103
2  7.698225 12.5688371 23.124130
3 25.587083  7.5330812  7.348549
4 10.705084  6.5245740 15.431941
5 11.292877  0.4838143  5.856601
6 27.150650  9.5497228  5.237531
```

**My Question:** Is it possible to keep columns in this data set based on the row number? For example, only keep columns where the 3rd row is greater than 7.3 and the 5th row is greater than 1?

```
new_data = my_data[which(my_data[3,] > 7.3 & my_data[5,] >  1 ), ]
```

The above code returns rows that do not match the desired condition:

```
          a        b         c
1  4.395244 2.895934 31.988103
3 25.587083 7.533081  7.348549
```

I would have wanted the above code to only return column "a" (all values of "a").

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this also return column "c" as well as "a"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change the position of `,` in your statement:

```
new_data = my_data[, which(my_data[3,] > 7.3 & my_data[5,] > 1)]
```

Comment: Also, `which` is not necessary here.